# Mcabber: Unable to connect to the server (Ejabberd)

Tags: ssl, client-server, xmpp, ejabberd

I have 2 linux machines, on one Ejabberd is running, and from another, my mcabber client is trying to connect to it. But, I am getting the following error message on client:

`Certificate is not trusted!Certificate hostname does not match expected hostname!Your status has been set: [_>o]`

I tried using the following configurations:
`set ssl_ignore_checks = 1`.But, still it didn't work.

Can anybody please help me with this certificate issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your certificate is not matching your domain name. Even if certificate if self-signed, it need to be generated for the proper domain.